# Copy members to std::vector

Tags: c++, boost, std, c++98

```
struct Node
{
    std::string name;
    ...
};

typedef std::vector<Node> Nodes;

Nodes nodes;
std::vector<std::string> names;
```

Is there a nice one-liner way of populating the vector names with Node::name for each item in nodes?

This is what I currently do:

```
names.reserve(nodes.size());
BOOST_FOREACH(Node node, nodes) 
{
    names.push_back(node.name);
}
```

I'm using C++98, std and boost.

Comment: C++98 is not really one-liner friendly

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "populating names with Node::name"?

Comment: Guess he wants to get the struct into the vector.

Comment: About the only way you'll get this into a one liner with C++98 is if you make an implicit conversion between `std::string` and `Node` (which is not recommended).

Comment: @Blacktempel: "populating the vector names with Node::name" suggests the OP wants to push back only the node names.

Comment: @Yuushi: Thats what I meant with `get the struct into the vector`. Didn't say get the whole struct into names[0], that would be kind of strange.

Comment: Ah sorry, I got it wrong. Nevermind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is much simpler with newer libraries (boost) and or standards (C++11), but you should be able to write a small functor:

```
struct ReadNodeName {
   std::string const & operator()(Node const & node) const {
      return node.name;
   }
};
```

And then use `std::transform`

```
std::transform(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(),
               std::back_inserter(names),
               ReadNodeName());
```

With boost, the functor could be just `boost::bind`, in C++11 you could use a lambda: `[](Node const & node) { return node.name; };`, in C++14 a shorter lambda `[](auto& n) { return n.name; }`:

```
std::transform(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(),
               std::back_inserter(names),
               [](auto & n){return n.name;});
```

---

Using boost bind -- beware, untested, I don't have access to boost

```
std::transform(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(),
               std::back_inserter(names),
               boost::bind(&Node::name, _1));
```

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas Do you mind showing us how the boost::bind might work? Thank!

Comment: I guess a plain non-member function would also be a good alternative here.

Comment: @Baz: Added *untested* code, but that should be close to the right thing

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). This takes care of the actual copying in one line. You will have to write a transformation function, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you add a `getName()` function to `Node`, you can do this:

```
std::transform(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), back_inserter(names), mem_fun(&Node::getName));
```

Comment: I'd like Node to feel more like a data container than a class. It starts feeling more and more like a class if I add more and more functions to it. This is why I define it using struct instead of class.

Comment: @Baz while I understand where you're coming from, adding member functions does not change anything about your object under the hood. It's still plain old data until you start adding in virtual functions etc.

Comment: You could just write a free function that takes a `Node` and returns its `string`, and pass the name of that function as the last argument to transform.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention boost, here is one liner with `boost::lambda`:

```
std::transform(nodes.begin(),nodes.end(), std::back_inserter(names), &boost::lambda::_1 ->* &Node::name );
```

Boost lambda cannot overload `.*` so first we need to get address `&`, and then use `->*` to get reference to member.